Visual Studio give an error when try to open one of my extension on it
My Visual Studio 2022 has been giving an "exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" error for a few days when I try to open one of the extensions that I have installed. It happened that I was using this extension and when I was done with it, I closed it, but a few moments later when I tried to open it again, I encountered this error. My guess is that when I finished working with it and closed it, it was not closed properly and it was frozen behind the scene, which causes it to get an error when Visual Studio tries to open it.
The solutions I tried for this problem are summarized in:
1- Removing and reinstalling the extension
2- Remove the ComponentModelCache folder from the path:
C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_a93e707d
3- Reset Visual Studio settings
4- Repairing Visual Studio
5- Windows update
6- Checking the output tab to see the cause of the error, which is empty when the error occurs
7- I checked the logs as much as possible and did not see anything
8- Removing and reinstalling latest version Visual Studio
A few tips:

Extension is updated.
I did not install any new extension that caused the error.
Visual Studio opens as Run As Administrator.
It is an organizational extension and others have no problem with it.
According to the picture, this extension is inside a pack, and the rest of the extensions in that pack have no problem in running.




Contact the developer, they can probably help debug it. Nothing really we can do here without seeing the extension code.

@mxmissile  thanks, I had encountered this problem once a few years ago, and as far as I can remember, I deleted a folder from the Visual Studio folders, and the problem was solved, but unfortunately I don't remember which folder it was, that's why I asked here, maybe someone knows which folder it was, or the way suggest another solution.
